# Bipolar junction transistor drawing more than 1 amp

Tags: transistors, short-circuit

I am trying to use a bipolar junction transistor to sink the current on an output pin:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3iYNO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

But when the base of Q1 is connected to 0V, and the base of Q2 is connected to 5V, there seems to be a large amount of current going through Q2 (1.28 amps). The only possible path that the current could take is from the base of Q2 to the emitter of Q2.

UPDATE: I meant to say "The only possible path that the current could take is from the base of Q2 to the **collector** of Q2."

Comment: Where is ground?  and where is Q2 - I only see Q1 and Q5.  Please check that the schematic you show represents the circuit you have.

Comment: You need resistors in the base leads of the transistors to limit base current, and thus collector/emitter current.  Also, an NPN emitter follower can only pull things up - it can't pull things down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You need resistors in the base leads of the transistors to limit base
>   current, and thus collector/emitter current. Also, an NPN emitter
>   follower can only pull things up - it can't pull things down. –  Peter
>   Bennett

Thanks!

I fixed the problem by adding a 10K resistor to the base. I also rearranged the transistors so that Q2 is able to pull the output down; the collector of Q2 is connected to the output, and the emitter of Q2 is connected to GND.